# How can I change button to 2 buttons onClick in ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic3

I want to create a button which by default shows ‘Add’ text on it and after click it should ’ - 1 +’ by which the user can add or remove items via pressing on it

when the items is 0 it should show Add again rather than showing '- 0 +'

[image]

Comment: Can you share current code that you have?

Answer (score 0):

Put a count property on the page which is initialised to zero. Use it to condition the minus button with an [*ngIF.](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives) Have the (click) handler for each add or remove one from the count. If the order can be loaded up subsequently - count number of lines and store that in the count property.

This is a sample click handler from an [ion button](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/button). with an [icon](https://ionicons.com/) associated in the html markup of a page component. Put the counter property in the underlying page component. Add any necessary service calls in to recall order, possibly using something like an ion-list for your details. Embed an ion-item inside the ion-list with an ion-label.

```
       <button ion-button *ngIf="itemsCount > 0"
              class="edtbtn"
              (click)="changeGvar(gvar)">
        <ion-icon name="redo"></ion-icon>
        &nbsp;Change
      </button>
```